# excluding bias for prediction in NN

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a continuous dataset, for which I built a neural network. Before running the NN, I have scaled the training data and added bias after each layer. I am pretty happy with training result, however, I am  facing a problem, when trying to build a predict method.

As I have said, the training data was scaled. The problem is, if I run un-scaled testing data with training weights, whole model will act differently and testing score will of course produce different result.

My question is, how to exclude bias from prediction model? Do I need to remove every weight out manually or are there and good practises around?

Comment: I think you simply need to apply the same scaling to your test data to solve your problem. This should work as long as your training and testing data is drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: @Imran Yes, I think this would be the best solution as well. Thank you.